# import variables with both character and numeric values from excel to SAS

Tags: excel, sas, character, numeric

I have a dataset in excel, variables contain values with both character and numeric formats.

> var1 --------    var2
>
> 352,45  ----- <34,5

when I import them into SAS, var2 becomes missing, how can I keep or impute "<34,5" for var2?

I use the following code to import:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= data
DATAFILE= "data1.xlsx" 
DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
RANGE="Sheet1$"; 
GETNAMES=YES;
MIXED=YES;
SCANTEXT=YES;
USEDATE=YES;
SCANTIME=YES;
RUN;
```

Comment: How are you importing the data ? What is the log showing ?

Comment: I added the code to my post

Comment: Did you try using the `XLSX` engine instead of the `EXCEL` engine?

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003289/sas-define-type-when-importing-xlsx-with-proc-import/39006151#39006151).

Answer (score 2):

**The quick answer**

Change a Windows registry entry using RegEdit. On my system, Windows 10, x64, Office 2016, the entry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRow
```

would change to

```
0
```

**The explanation**

The `Proc IMPORT DBMS=EXCEL` is inferring column `var2` is numeric content because it has not scanned enough Excel rows to discover there is some non-numeric content.  So on that inference when non-numeric content is reached the procedure replaces it with a missing value.

You will have to

1. Force IMPORT to scan enough rows to find non-numerics in a column (if present).

   - Causes IMPORT to define those columns (variables) as character type
2. Post-process the imported data set in a DATA step

   - Performs transformations that convert those *expected* numeric variables into actual numeric variable.

**Scanning more rows - Excel**

There is no `Proc IMPORT` option for changing the number of Excel rows that are scanned.

`Proc IMPORT DBMS=Excel` in Windows uses Microsoft technology to read Excel files. In SAS version <9.2 Phase 2 the technology is Jet and new versions use ACE.  Each of these technologies uses the **Windows** registry to obtain the parameter `TypeGuessingRows` which is how many rows should be scanned before inferring a column is character, numeric, or date.  When the parameter value is **0**, all rows are scanned before inferring.

[SAS Documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acpcref&docsetTarget=n0msy4hy1so0ren1acm90iijxn8j.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) "SAS/ACCESS® 9.4 Interface to PC Files: Reference, Fourth Edition" chapter "Microsoft Excel Workbook Files" details the **Windows** registry entry that will need to be changed based on system and Office installation.  As mentioned in the *the quick* my system has

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRow
```

The default of `8` rows was changed to `0`.

**Bonus: Scanning more rows - Delimited files**

These would be text files with fields delimited by commas, tabs, or some other character.

`Proc IMPORT DBMS=CSV` can be forced to scan all rows by using GUESSINGROWS **statement**

```
Proc IMPORT --all my options-- out=import_raw;
  GUESSINGROWS=MAX; * statement;
run;
```

**Step 2 - Post processing**

Here is some sample code showing how a known 'tricky' column is converted to a same named numeric column.  The *rule* is that a value `<####` will be converted to `####`.

```
data import;
  set import_raw (rename=var2=var2_raw);

  if var2_raw =: '<' then 
    var2 = input(substr(var2_raw,2), best12.);
  else
    var2 = input(var2_raw,best12.);

  drop var2_raw;
run;
```

Your actual rules for transformation may vary -- for instance you might need to add a `$1` column `var2_relation` that takes on values `=`, `<`, or `>`.  Or you might compress the value, removing all non-number characters, before doing the input() conversion.

It would be another question if you have problems coding a solution that does the same transform across all variables.

Comment: thanks, but GUESSINGROWS doesn't work for excel files, but only for csv. Is there anything that can do the same job for excel?

Comment: At which Excel row does var2 first exhibit < ?

Comment: It exists only in row 27 and 30 of Excel file.

Comment: You will have to change a Windows Registry setting. See updated answer

Comment: I think if you use the XLSX engine instead of EXCEL engine then you do not need to change the number of rows that it examines.  It should check the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, likely the Excel engine is not scanning far enough down to find the character values.

The XLSX engine, new I believe in 9.3 and generally fully functional for both import and export in 9.4, will do a better job scanning for variable types.  It's fairly easy to use, just swap `DBMS=EXCEL` to `DBMS=XLSX`.  It won't be perfectly identical if you have (for example) `GETNAMES=NO`, but for most uses it's identical.

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= data
DATAFILE= "data1.xlsx" 
DBMS=XLSX REPLACE;
SHEET="Sheet1"; 
GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

Comment: What doesn’t work??  DBMS=XLSX certainly does work in 9.4.  Does it not fix your character/numeric issue?

Comment: This is the log which I get by using XLSX:  (It doesn't happen for Excel)                                                                                                                    3365  PROC IMPORT OUT= data1
3366  DATAFILE= "data.xlsx"
3367  DBMS=XLSX REPLACE;
3368  SHEET="Sheet1$";
3369  GETNAMES=YES;
3370  RUN;

ERROR: Couldn't find sheet in spreadsheet

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE IMPORT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.04 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

Comment: If you just want the first sheet there is no need for the `SHEET=` statement.  Are you sure the file is an actual XLSX file?  Make a copy and change the extension to ZIP and check if you can see the XML files inside the ZIP file.

Comment: Now I can see both numeric and character values, but when I try to combine the dataset with the others, I get the following error,  ERROR: Variable day__14 has been defined as both character and numeric.
ERROR: Variable day_2 has been defined as both character and numeric.    I used put(day_2,6.) to convert all to character but I still get the same error

Answer (score -1):

Have you tought about using infile instead of proc import?
Also if the number and characters are all in the same colomn you will need to force it to characters.

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/166-2008.pdf

The code below is a sample I have from a loop but you should be able to figure it out. Note that when a colomn is followed with $ in the infile statement it forces the colomn to be characters!

```
 filename file&i "&fdir";   /*THIS ASSIGN FILE NAME RELATED WITH THE DIRECTORY IN PREVIOUS FILE*/
      data &name; /*USE THE FULL PATH OF THE FILE NEEDED AS PER 1ST TABLE*/
LENGTH  BAN $10.;
    LENGTH  SUBSCRIBER_NO   $10.;
    LENGTH  TRANSACTION_DATE    $18.;
    LENGTH  OPT1    $18.;
        INFILE file&i delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD LRECL=32767 FIRSTOBS=2 flowover;
        input SUBSCRIBER_NO $   BAN $   OPT1 $  TRANSACTION_DATE $  TRANSACTION_TYPE $  ITEM_ID $   MSID $  NIN1 $  ACTIVATION_TYPE $   STORE_CODE $    OPT8 $  OPT10 $     OPT9 $  WES $   BILL_CYCLE $    LANGUAGE_CODE $     REGION $    COMPANY_CODE $  PRICE_PLAN $    COMMIT_START_DATE $     SYS_CREATION_DATE $     RENEWAL_DATE $  ESN_TYPE $  ACCOUNT_TYPE $  EFFECTIVE_DATE $    INIT_ACTIVATION_DATE $  TENURE $    DATA $  PRICE_PLAN_DATA $   OPT3 $  PRICE_PLAN_DESC $   MSF $   PRICE_PLAN_SERIES $     ACTIVATION_DATE $   OPT5 $  TERM_STATUS $   OPT4 $  FIRST_NAME $    LAST_BUSINESS_NAME $    ADDRESS_ATTENTION $     USER_NAME $     ADDRESS_NAME_1 $    ADDRESS_NAME_2 $    ADDRESS_NAME_3 $    CITY $  province $  POSTAL_CODE $   home_no $   work_no $   MKT_ACCOUNT_TYPE $  ESN_EFFECTIVE_DATE $    CABLE_FOOTPRINT $   COMMON_IND $    CS_VIP_CLASS $  OPT2 $  OPT6 $  OPT7 $  KEYCODE $   CAMPAIGN_CODE $     CAMPAIGN_CYCLE $    CAMPAIGN_DATE $     CAMPAIGN_DESCRIPTION $  CAMPAIGN_TYPE $     EMAIL $     MOP $   SERIAL_NUMBER $     ACTIVATION_SUB_TYPE $   SALES_REP $ ;
      run;

      data import;
        set %if ne 1 %then import;
            &name;
      run;
      %let i = %eval(&i+1);
      filename  file&i clear;
```

Comment: This would only work if the Excel data was exported to a csv file first.

Comment: Thanks! In this webpage which you have linked, there is information for changing windows registry settings when office has version 2013 or so but no info for version 2016. The version of my office is  2016, do you know how one could change the registry setting?

Comment: You can poke around in RegEdit or use RegEdit Find feature to locate the entry for `TypeGuessingRows`.